# How can I toggle between adding and removing the same class in jQuery with an onClick function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to toggle between adding and removing a class to hide / show a popup window. 
I am going for something that resembles a computer screen with window browsers so when an icon is clicked a window pops up and so does a tab at the bottom of the navigation bar that you can click to toggle between opening and closing the window.

Here is an example of what I have so far: http://jsfiddle.net/fjmnqx7e/288/

I got the pop-up to close when clicking on the "toggle button" however I can't get it to re-open.

Thank you in advance!

```js
$('.icon3').on("click", function() {
  $(".windowframe, .window-content, .navbartabs").addClass("active");
  $(".navbartabs").css("display", "inline-block");
});

$(".close").on("click", function() {
  $(".windowframe, .window-content").removeClass("active");
  $(".navbartabs").css("display", "none");
});

$(".navbartabs").on("click", function() {
  $(".navbartabs").css("display", "inline-block");
});
```

```css
iframe {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
}

.windowframe {
  /*Hides pop-up when there is no "active" class*/
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  background: #ffffff;
  border: 3px solid #666666;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  left: 25%;
}

.windowframe.active {
  /*displays pop-up when "active" class is present*/
  visibility: visible;
  text-align: center;
}

.window-content {
  /*Hides pop-up content when there is no "active" class */
  visibility: hidden;
}

.window-content.active {
  /*Shows pop-up content when "active" class is present */
  visibility: visible;
}

.navbartabs {
  display: none;
  margin-left: 70px;
  height: 20px;
  width: 100px;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="draggable" class="icon3">
  <div class="icons">
    <a href="#"><img src="http://paynomind.us/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/hat-icon-03.png"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="iconTXT"> hats </div>
</div>


<div class="windowframe">
  <button class="close"> close </button>
  <div class="window-content">
    <iframe src="paynomind.us"></iframe>
  </div>
</div>


<div id="nav bar">
  <button class="navbartabs close"> toggle button </button>
  <div>
```

Comment: Friend, there is a .toggleClass() function. http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to use css. You could use jquery `toggleClass()`.

If you want to toggle class then you could use `toggleClass()`

```
$(".windowframe, .window-content, .navbartabs").toggleClass('active')
```

Working code

```js
$('.icon3').on("click", function() {
  $(".windowframe, .window-content, .navbartabs").toggleClass("active");
  $(".navbartabs").css("display", "inline-block");
});

$(".close").on("click", function() {
  $(".windowframe, .window-content").toggleClass("active");
  $(".navbartabs").css("display", "none");
});

$(".navbartabs").on("click", function() {
  $(".navbartabs").css("display", "inline-block");
});
```

```css
iframe {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
}

.windowframe {
  /*Hides pop-up when there is no "active" class*/
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  background: #ffffff;
  border: 3px solid #666666;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  left: 25%;
}

.windowframe.active {
  /*displays pop-up when "active" class is present*/
  visibility: visible;
  text-align: center;
}

.window-content {
  /*Hides pop-up content when there is no "active" class */
  visibility: hidden;
}

.window-content.active {
  /*Shows pop-up content when "active" class is present */
  visibility: visible;
}

.navbartabs {
  display: none;
  margin-left: 70px;
  height: 20px;
  width: 100px;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="draggable" class="icon3">
  <div class="icons">
    <a href="#"><img src="http://paynomind.us/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/hat-icon-03.png"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="iconTXT"> hats </div>
</div>


<div class="windowframe">
  <button class="close"> close </button>
  <div class="window-content">
    <iframe src="paynomind.us"></iframe>
  </div>
</div>


<div id="nav bar">
  <button class="navbartabs close"> toggle button </button>
  <div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) function to add/remove active class.

Here is your code.

```
 $('.icon3').on("click", function() {
         $(".windowframe, .window-content, .navbartabs").addClass("active");
         $(".navbartabs").css("display", "inline-block");
     });

     $(".close").on("click", function() {
         $(".windowframe, .window-content").removeClass("active");
         $(".navbartabs").css("display", "none");
     });

     $(".navbartabs").on("click", function() {
         $(".windowframe, .window-content").toggleClass('active');
     });
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fjmnqx7e/300/)

Answer (score 0):

Try This Code

Using `toggel Button` you can `show hide popup`

```js
$('.icon3').on("click", function() {
  $(".windowframe, .window-content,    .navbartabs").addClass("active");
  $(".navbartabs").css("display", "inline-block");
});

$(".close").on("click", function() {
  if ($(".window-content").hasClass('active')) {
    $(".windowframe, .window-content").removeClass("active");
    $(".navbartabs").css("display", "none");
  } else {
    $(".windowframe, .window-content,    .navbartabs").addClass("active");
    $(".navbartabs").css("display", "inline-block");
  }
});

$(".navbartabs").on("click", function() {
  $(".navbartabs").css("display", "inline-block");
});
```

```css
iframe {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
}

.windowframe {
  /*Hides pop-up when there is no "active" class*/
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  background: #ffffff;
  border: 3px solid #666666;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  left: 25%;
}

.windowframe.active {
  /*displays pop-up when "active" class is present*/
  visibility: visible;
  text-align: center;
}

.window-content {
  /*Hides pop-up content when there is no "active" class */
  visibility: hidden;
}

.window-content.active {
  /*Shows pop-up content when "active" class is present */
  visibility: visible;
}

.navbartabs {
  display: none;
  margin-left: 70px;
  height: 20px;
  width: 100px;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="draggable" class="icon3">
  <div class="icons">
    <a href="#"><img src="http://paynomind.us/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/hat-icon-03.png"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="iconTXT"> hats </div>
</div>


<div class="windowframe">
  <button class="close"> close </button>
  <div class="window-content">
    <iframe src="paynomind.us"></iframe>
  </div>
</div>


<div id="nav bar">
  <button class="navbartabs close"> toggle button </button>
  <div>
```

OR Use `toggleClass`

```
$(".windowframe, .window-content").toggleClass('active');
```

Answer (score 0):

When you click the `Toggle Button`, make sure if it has the class `close`. Depending on this class you can then show/hide the `windowframe`

Plus, you must make sure that the class button triggered when hiding both `toggle and windowframe` must be `.windowframe .close` and not `.close` only, because then when you click the `Toggle Button` that has the class `.close` it will trigger this function and hide both `Windowframe and Toggle Button`

```js
$('.icon3').on("click", function(){
  showWindowframe(1);
  showToggleBtn(1);
});

$(".windowframe .close").on("click", function(){
  showWindowframe(0);
  showToggleBtn(0);
});

$(".navbartabs").on("click", function(){
  if ($(this).hasClass("close")) {
    $(this).removeClass("close");
    showWindowframe(0);
  }
  else {
    $(this).addClass("close")
    showWindowframe(1);
  }
});
 
function showWindowframe(status) {
  if (status) {
    $(".windowframe, .window-content").addClass("active");
  }
  else {
    $(".windowframe, .window-content").removeClass("active");
  }
}
 
function showToggleBtn(status) {
  if (status) {
    $(".navbartabs").css("display", "inline-block").addClass("close");
  }
  else {
    $(".navbartabs").css("display","none");
  }
}
```

```css
iframe {
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   padding:0;
   margin: 0;
   border: none;
   overflow: hidden;
   display: flex;
}

.windowframe{
   /*Hides pop-up when there is no "active" class*/
   visibility:hidden;
   position:absolute;
   background:#ffffff;
   border:3px solid #666666;
   width:50%;
   height:50%;
   left:25%; 
}

.windowframe.active{
   /*displays pop-up when "active" class is present*/
   visibility:visible;
   text-align:center;
}

.window-content {
   /*Hides pop-up content when there is no "active" class */
   visibility:hidden;
}

.window-content.active {
   /*Shows pop-up content when "active" class is present */
   visibility:visible;
}

.navbartabs {
    display:none;
    margin-left:70px;
    height:20px;
    width:100px;
    float:right;

 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="draggable" class ="icon3">
    <div class="icons">
        <a href="#"><img src="http://paynomind.us/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/hat-icon-03.png"></a></div>
    <div class="iconTXT"> hats </div> 
</div>   


<div class="windowframe">
    <button class="close"> close </button>
    <div class="window-content">
     <iframe src="paynomind.us"></iframe>
     </div>
 </div>


 <div id="nav bar">
      <button class="navbartabs close"> toggle button </button>
 <div>
```